# create-react-app not working due to fetching issue

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

I want to create a react app although "npx create-react-app [app-name]" won't work in my project folder. I get the an "Incorrect integrity when fetching from the cache" error although I'm not familiar with why it's not fetching. The error is below.

=================================

Vincents-MacBook-Pro:Personal-Projects Vince$ npx create-react-app my-app

Creating a new React app in /Users/Vince/Documents/Coding-Projects/Personal-Projects/my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

yarn add v1.19.0
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
error Incorrect integrity when fetching from the cache
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts --cwd /Users/mountainthief/Documents/Coding-Projects/Personal-Projects/test-app has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
Deleting test-app/ from /Users/Vince/Documents/Coding-Projects/Personal-Projects
Done.

=================================

I've tried "npm cache clean --force" and uninstalling yarn to no avail.

What could I be missing?

npm cache clean --force
uninstall yarn

Creating a new React app in /Users/Vince/Documents/Coding-Projects/Personal-Projects/my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

yarn add v1.19.0
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
error Incorrect integrity when fetching from the cache
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts --cwd /Users/mountainthief/Documents/Coding-Projects/Personal-Projects/test-app has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
Deleting test-app/ from /Users/Vince/Documents/Coding-Projects/Personal-Projects
Done.

I expected a functional React-app complete with node-modules although I received the error:

yarn add v1.19.0
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
error Incorrect integrity when fetching from the cache
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Comment: Seems like yarn cache issue to me. Have you tried `yarn cache clean`?

Answer (score 2):

You can also see where the cache is with yarn cache dir.

```
yarn cache dir
```

Running yarn cache dir will print out the path where yarn’s global cache is currently stored.  When you do a

```
yarn cache clean
```

You can check the folder actually cleans.  If that fails you can manually delete it.  [yarn cache documentation](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/cache/)

Comment: For some reason npm uninstall yarn didn't cut it. However, manually looking up and removing yarn did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

please run both commands again then install your app. Basically this types of error coming due to some package dependencies. So please install all both packages again.

npm install -g create-react-app
and reinstall yarn

If you getting same error after install both the please send me yarn and node version.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it has resolved with upgrading global yarn packages.

```
$ yarn global upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

What fixed it for me was to delete the entire global yarn cache dir in the file system which I got via `yarn cache dir`, here's a one liner for that:

```sh
rm -rf `yarn cache dir`
```

After that `yarn global upgrade` made it work again:

```
yarn create react-app my-app --typescript
```

```
Happy hacking!
✨  Done in 22.60s.
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a simple folder permissions issue for me, a sudo resolved:

```
sudo npx create-react-app myApp
```